# How to enable socket IO and websocket on a CentOS Web Panel?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, webrtc, centos7, cwp

I have installed a CentOS 7 server and CentOS Web Panel (cwp) for hosting server. I would like to get WebRTC software for peer to peer connections. I am developing my software through XAMPP. When I try WebRTC on the localhost in the local computer that gives me connectivity but on the webserver I do not get any output.

I just get the following error

> 'OT.Publisher Access Denied: Permission Denied: End-user denied
>   permission to hardware devices (getUserMedia error: NotAllowedError)
>   Note: Chrome requires HTTPS for camera and microphone access.'

I have installed nodejs on the server. Now I have a few questions:

1. How do enable WebSocket?
2. Which port shall I use for WebRTC communication?
3. If I need multiple websites for WebRTC/video app communication on the same server what shall I do?
4. Do I need to install Express.js and Socket.io in every website root directory?

Answer (score -1):

The answer is in the question, just install SSL on your server, and it will be work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider posting this as a comment instead of an answer. After you have gained a certain reputation points you will be able to post comments in other questions/answers.